# How can I count how many times I visit a specific domain?

Tags: web, usage-statistics

I'm interested in writing a program (or possibly using another means) to update a counter every time I visit a specific domain, say "wikipedia.org" or "twitter.com", from any browser. As far as I can tell, no such program exists. The problem is that I don't know where to begin: I don't know how an external program would be able to tell when a browser requests a page from a given domain.

Ideally, I would like to store this value in a simple text file, for example:

```
twitter.com   = 123
wikipedia.org = 456
```

The program will run in the background and update the file each time one of the domains is visited.

I am open to other solutions-- perhaps it can be done from within the browser, or maybe this data is already stored somewhere and I just need to process it.

Answer (score 0):

You may write a Browser plugin will allow you to do this.Below link is for firefox same thing can be done for IE, Chrome etc. Required data should be available in browser history.
 [Firefox extension](http://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/)